# select outlineView row with nsbutton

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

i working with swift 4 for osx.
i have nsoutlineview with custom cells.
in each cell is a button.

in my outlineView-Controller-Class is an IBAction action for this button:

```
@IBAction func showInfo(_ sender: NSButton) {     

   // Get the row of clicked button
   print(myOutlineView.row(for: sender as NSView))

}
```

but i also would like to select the row of this button.
i guess i have to use this command:

```
myOutlineView.selectRowIndexes(<NSIndexSet>, byExtendingSelection: <Bool>)
```

but how can i get the NSIndexSet value?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

okay, i found the solution:

```
myOutlineView.selectRowIndexes(IndexSet(integer: myOutlineView.row(for: sender as NSView)), byExtendingSelection: false)
```